# Why does add-hook allow `hook' to be void?

Tags: emacs, elisp

From <kbd>C-h f add-hook</kbd>:

```
HOOK should be a symbol, and FUNCTION may be any valid function.  If
HOOK is void, it is first set to nil.  If HOOK's value is a single
function, it is changed to a list of functions.
```

and from the code:

```
(defun add-hook (hook function &optional append local)
  ...
  (or (boundp hook) (set hook nil))
  (or (default-boundp hook) (set-default hook nil))
  ...
```

What is this good for? I assume it's somehow useful or else it wouldn't be there... I just can't think of a good use for it...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It allows you to set hook variables before the packages which define them have been loaded.

Comment: mgalgs: Note that it is the *value* of the hook variable which is being set to `nil` (i.e. an empty list). So it is simply initialising that variable when it's void.

Comment: Makes sense. Otherwise we'd have `eval-after-load` all over the place, or would have to be very careful about ordering in our init files.